# How to output kafka consumer property?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have kafka installed on some server, and a local consumer.
I want to know the value of a property, more specifically : max.poll.interval.ms

How do i supposed to do it?

Comment: `max.poll.interval.ms` is property for your consumer. You have to change it if you need something more than default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you didn't start the consumer asking about its configuration.
Anyway, it could depend on the client library, if it's the upstream Java one or something else. The Java one prints the configuration on startup so you should check the log. There is no way for getting it at runtime.

Comment: i put messages into kafka , but my consumer waits for too long to read it

Comment: the poll in the consumer returns as soon as it gets messages. Without the consumer logic I don't know how much often the poll is called. Maybe the problem could be on the producer side which sends in batch so it depends on parameters like batch.size and linger.ms. Other than that, even acks is important because if you have "all" and not all the ISR got the message, it's not available to the consumer. Too many variables without more details on the application architecture and configuration.